# Custom configuration of nuget

Tags: visual-studio-2017, nuget, nuget-package

I need a custom configuration of nuget packages.
How I understood it so far there are two ways how to manage nugets.
The first one is `PackageReference` and the other is `package.config`.

When one uses `PackageReference` packages are downloaded into computer/user wide repository and used directly in projects via references.

When `package.config` is used packages are downoaded into `packageSources` folder (from `NuGet.Config`) and the installed into `repositoryPath` folder.
Hence every package is on a disk at least twice.

I would like to use nugets to distribute content that could be potentially big.

Is it possible to configure nugets in a way that the packages are on a disk only once? Somehow like `PackageReference` but not using the global wide repository, only the project repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to configure nugets in a way that the packages are on a disk only once? Somehow like PackageReference but not using the global wide repository, only the project repository?

Yes, you can place a `NuGet.Config` file next to the solution with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <configuration>
    <config>
      <add key="globalPackagesFolder" value=".\packages"/>
    </config>
</configuration>
```

Then restart the Visual Studio, and re-open the solution and right click on the solution, select Restore NuGet Packages. All the packages are stored in the project repository.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I assume one must use PackageReference with this solution ?

Comment: @JiříLechner, Yes, it only works on `PackageReference`. For the package.config, the default package repository is the project repository. So, if your solution have any project use `PackageReference`, above setting will be work on it, if not, all the nuget packages are stored in the project repository

Comment: I mark it as answered althought I forgot to mention I use native code solution/projects. Hence it is not usable for me. PackageReference doesnt work for .vcxproj projects.